# I want the instance of the Background service which is running

Tags: android, android-service

In this, the service is been create repeated times but I need to get the instance of running service so that I can start the timer task. The object of this service can get from any activity. The basic aim is to start the timer task after the particular button click.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        MyService mService;
        boolean mBound = false;
        int b=0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            findViewById(R.id.btn_start_timer).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mBound) {
                       mService.runTimerTask(++b);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // Bind to LocalService
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }

        /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
        private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                           IBinder service) {
                // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
                MyService.LocalBinder binder = (MyService.LocalBinder) service;
                mService = binder.getService();
                mBound = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                mBound = false;
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ServiceManager class and route all methods through that and store it in the application:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
  ...
  private ServiceManager serviceManager = ...;

  public ServiceManager getServiceManager() {
    return serviceManager;
  }
}
```

In MainActivity:

```
ServiceManager serviceManager = ((YourApplication)getApplication()).getServiceManager();
MyService runningService = serviceManager.getRunningService();
```

The ServiceManager would handle unbinding etc and all methods that involve the state of the service. So you just ask the ServiceManager for the running service. Where you have `ServiceConnection::onServiceConnected` doing the work, delegate that work to the ServiceManager so it can keep state and share it with the rest of the application:

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                           IBinder service) {
  ((YourApplication)getApplication()).getServiceManager().bind(service);
}
```

It's a general technique for sharing object state across an application but you'd need to tailor it to fit.